# What is the rationale for the C++ standard not allowing reinterpret_cast<int>( aFloatValue )?

Tags: c++, floating-point

Or equivalently

```
    reinterpret_cast<int64>( aDoubleValue )
```

Allowing such a reinterpret_cast would not introduce any aliasing issues.

I understand that using memcpy to replicate bytes from a variable of one type into a variable of another type can achieve the necessary effect.  And I understand that mature compilers with powerful optimizers can do wonderful things with such memcpy constructs.

That said I happen to be a compiler-writer.  I am very aware of the **many** forms of optimization that must exist and the **many** preconditions that have to be met in order to pull off those dramatic optimizations.  Do we really want to assume that every compiler is that powerful or that every programmer will write code successfully satisfying all of the necessary preconditions?  Can we really fault programmers using non-mainstream compilers for being dubious that such a hoped-for optimization will occur?

The need to inspect the bits of a floating point values arises fairly often.  Do we really want to insist that every programmer encountering such a need traffic in address-taken variables, char* exceptions to type aliasing rules, memcpy magic, etc?

Comment: Did you try this with a *pointer* to the value?

Comment: "*The need to inspect the bits of a floating point values arises fairly often.*" I'm very curious as to what you're doing that you need to "fairly often" do this.

Comment: @NicolBolas I am a compiler-writer at a company with a heavy investment in its math libraries.  Both in the optimizer's abstract interpretation of floating point functions and in the implementation of our math libraries I often have to overcome the IEEE standard's notion that +0.0 equals -0.0.  Being able to compare floating values known to be "some flavor of zero" as integers is more efficient than code that extracts sign bits, especially when the instruction set supports it directly (e.g. x86's SSE).
I would be happy with an std function that return the raw bits.

Answer (score 1):

The "new" (now pretty old) forms of casting provided in C++ are all basically subsets of things you can do with C-style casts ("basically" because they have a few minor additions like dealing with references, that just don't exist in C).

To get the equivalent of a reinterpret_cast with a C-style cast, you do something like:

```
int a = *(int *)&some_float;
```

So, with a `reinterpret_cast`, you do pretty much the same things, just changing the syntax for the cast itself with a `reinterpret_cast` instead:

```
int a = *reinterpret_cast<int *>&some_float;
```

As for defining what this does, so you can do it without violating any strict aliasing rules and such: I suspect the committee would probably be happy to consider a really well written proposal--I suspect the problem right now is that most think it would take a lot of work, and payoff would be minimal.

If the real intent is to support looking at the bits of a floating point number, it might be simpler to define something like a constructor for a `bitset::bitset<float>` or something on that order, to give a type that's already explicitly defined to give access to bits (though it would still probably be non-trivial to define how it's supposed to work in a way that's at all portable).

Comment: I like the bitset idea - an unambiguous semantics/served purpose, can't lead to type abuses.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Did you think I wasn't aware of that? If so, what did you think the "**without** violating any strict aliasing rules and such" referred to?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a function that converts a float into its sequence of bits, `memcpy` can do that without running afoul of the strict aliasing rule:

```
unsigned int ConvertFloat(float f)
{
  unsigned int ret;
  std::memcpy(&ret, &f, sizeof(unsigned int));
  return ret;
}
```

[Live example.](https://godbolt.org/g/UyqdFe)

You could even make a general template function for converting one type to another. One that would `static_assert` or SFINAE-check if the arguments are trivially-copyable.

In your line of work, converting floats to integers is a semi-frequent operation. But that's simply not true for most C++ users (or even most C users). So there is no widespread *need* for such a conversion operation.

Furthermore, the C++ standard doesn't require an implementation to provide any particular representation of a `float`. So even if the standard provided such a function, it couldn't tell you what it actually returned. There's not even guarantee that `float` can fit into an `unsigned int`.

Comment: "Furthermore, the C++ standard doesn't require an implementation to provide any particular representation of a float. So even if the standard provided such a function, it couldn't tell you what it actually returned. There's not even guarantee that float can fit into an unsigned int."  That feels like a pretty weak argument given all of the trouble the standard goes to to explain what to expect and what not to expect when reinterpret_casting between integral types and pointers.

Comment: @JohnYates: The most the standard says about integer/pointer casts is that, if the integer is big enough to hold it, then you can convert that integer back and get the same pointer (and that null pointers become zero and vice-versa). Other than that, it says *nothing*. There isn't even a guarantee that the implementation must support an integer type large enough to hold a pointer value (intptr_t is *optional*). There is some non-normative text about the value not being intended to be "surprising", but that doesn't mean anything in terms of behavior.

Comment: I think you just made my point.  Your previous comment about the relative sizes of floating point data type and integral types seems to me entirely parallel to the standard's point about the size of pointer types.  I would be happy with an equally weak commitment for floating point data.